# How might I improve my changepoint modeling with pymc3?

Tags: bayesian, inference, change-point

I am having trouble getting any estimates to render with `pymc3` for a changepoint model. I am wondering if someone more experienced with Bayesian data analysis could offer some opinions as to what I might do to try to improve my modeling attempts at my data that looks like this:

[image]

My code is as follows:

```
with pm.Model(coords=coords) as switchpoint_gauss:
    '''
    switchpoint guassian
    '''
    freeze_idx = pm.Data("freeze_idx", df.freeze_p, dims='obs_id')

    # Priors for pre- and post-switch intercepts and slopes
    intercept_1 = pm.Uniform('intercept_1', lower=0, upper=1)
    intercept_2 = pm.Uniform('intercept_2', lower=0, upper=1)
    beta_1 = pm.Normal("beta_1", mu=0, sigma=5)
    beta_2 = pm.Normal("beta_2", mu=-1, sigma=1)
    # switchpoint
    switchpoint = pm.DiscreteUniform('switchpoint', lower=0.05, upper=0.95, testval=0.8)
    intercept = pm.math.switch(switchpoint < df.freeze_p, intercept_1, intercept_2)
    x_coeff = pm.math.switch(switchpoint < df.freeze_p, beta_1, beta_2)

    # model error
    eps = pm.Exponential("sigma", 1.0)

    # expected value of y
    mu = intercept + x_coeff * df.freeze_p

    # Data likelihood
    y = pm.Normal("y", mu=mu, sigma=eps, observed=df.dev_metric, dims='obs_id')

    start = pm.find_MAP()
    step1 = pm.NUTS([intercept_1, intercept_2, beta_1, beta_2, eps])
    step2 = pm.Metropolis([switchpoint])

# Inference button (TM)!
with switchpoint_gauss:
    switchpoint_gauss_idata = pm.sample(draws=25000,
                                        step=[step1, step2],
                                        start=start,
                                        cores=4,
                                        tune=2000,
                                        return_inferencedata=True)
```

My results in turn look like:

[image]

And:

[image]

Comment: Feel you, I have had trouble with pretty much the same model. Even with metropolis for the changepoint, it either never settles down or drifts to the edges in my simulated examples. I have had some better luck with integrating out the changepoint entirely, https://andrewpwheeler.com/2020/12/26/a-changepoint-logistic-model-in-pystan/.

Comment: An alternative parameterization that may make sense seeing your data is with a plateau, https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2020/12/14/segmented-regression-sas.html. So if flatlining with some error around ~0.835 makes sense for your data, may give that a whirl.

Comment: This doesn't answer your question directly, but unless you need to use PyMC3 specifically - I've found that changepoints can be modelled more easily (and often more effectively) using the Prophet time series package. You can also incorporate uncertainty analysis into the model through specifying a defined interval width and mcmc_samples (to measure the uncertainty in trend and seasonality respectively): https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/uncertainty_intervals.html. Again, sorry to sidestep the question somewhat as you asked about PyMC3 specifically, but you might find Prophet of use.

Comment: Thanks for all the feedback! Will look into this all!